# Which obfuscator generates this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I need a javascript obfuscator. I came across this code where the function name and the parameter names have been obfuscated.

I've looked UglifyJS and Google Closure but they seam to just minimize the code.

Do you know which obfuscator has that capability?

```
function oa(a,b,c){return a.call.apply(a.bind,arguments)}function pa(a,b,c){if(!a)throw Error();if(2<arguments.length){var d=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,2);return function(){var c=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);Array.prototype.unshift.apply(c,d);return a.apply(b,c)}}return 
function(){return a.apply(b,arguments)}}function qa(a,b,c){qa=Function.prototype.bind&&-1!=Function.prototype.bind.toString().indexOf("native code")?oa:pa;return qa.apply(null,arguments)}
function ra(a,b){var c=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);return function(){var b=c.slice();b.push.apply(b,arguments);return a.apply(this,b)}}var x=Date.now||function(){return+new Date};function y(a,b){var c=a.split("."),d=q;c[0]in d||!d.execScript||d.execScript("var "+c[0]);for(var e;c.length&&(e=c.shift());)!c.length&&u(b)?d[e]=b:d[e]?d=d[e]:d=d[e]={}}
function z(a,b){function c(){}c.prototype=b.prototype;a.m=b.prototype;a.prototype=new c;a.prototype.constructor=a;a.th=function(a,c,f){for(var g=Array(arguments.length-2),k=2;k<arguments.length;k++)g[k-2]=arguments[k];return b.prototype[c].apply(a,g)}};var sa;var ta=String.prototype.trim?function(a){return a.trim()}:function(a){return a.replace(/^[\s\xa0]+|[\s\xa0]+$/g,"")};
```

Comment: When you looked at UglifyJS, did you enable the Mangler?

Comment: UglifyJS should do this unless you tell it not to.

Comment: except top-level `-mt` or `--mangle-toplevel` — mangle names in the toplevel scope too (by default we don’t do this).

Answer (score 0):

UglifyJS it is. Thanks everyone for the quick reply.